# How do you start Pygame window maximized?

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

I've been looking everywhere about how to start a pygame window maximized. Not Fullscreen nor borderless, but as if the user clicked on maximize button.

All the posts I've read on internet are from 6-7 years ago, and I understand that since pygame hasn't been updated from 2009 may be still using old SDL1 instead of newest SDL2 and therefore all the answers are still valid, but I'd like to have an updated response from someone who is actually into PyGame and may have a solution today that wasn't possible then.

My code looks like this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((config.WIN_WIDTH, config.WIN_HEIGHT), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Also on the topic, I kinda feel that Pygame is old and unmantained. I've been looking for alternatives at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries
but I can't still decide for any better option than PyGame because I see that most of them are also unmantained or updated once per year. I know that updating a game engine is not something to be done everyday, but at least a commit or two every month would be amazing.

So please, if you know a better option than PyGame for a Game library, doesn't have to be an engine, just create a window and give basic APIs for drawing into it is enough, let me know and I'll give it a try.
Also, if you have a very good reason to not develop games in Python and chose another language please let me know and I'll take in very consideration your opinion. My project is almost started and I'm still able to change my programming language for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This guy does it through user32 with ctypes, dunno if it works though, haven't tested: http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Oct-2007/msg00127.html

Comment: such a whole workaround just for that. Thanks for the response, I may use it if noone else offers a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

For a pretty straight forward method in windows you can execute this code right after you open your window.  This will maximize the window, not full screen it.

```
import win32gui, win32con

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```